# I have a problem with the sorting result of the database SQLite of my Android app

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is not a duplicated question. It is not about how to sort the database information, I already did that and and it's correctly working.

I have a problem with the sorting result of my Android app database when I close and open it again.

I want to make an app where I can put information in my database and then sort and display them.

I wrote the code and everything is fine, but the only problem is that when I close the app and open it again the sorting result is that way.

If for example I open the app and I write in my database 2 then 3 then 1 the sorting result will be 1-2-3.

When I close the app, open it again and write 3-1-2 the sorting result will be: 1-2-3-1-2-3 which is the sorting result of the first time I opened the app + the sorting result of the second time I opened the app and not the sorting result of all the database which is: 1-1-2-2-3-3.

Do you have an idea of what I should do or modify to get the result I want?

This is the code for generating the cursor

```
Cursor c =bdd.query(Program_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {Numannee, NumSem,Numjour, Heure, Minute, NomEvent, Adresse,Photo, Presentation, URL}, Numannee+" = ? AND "+NumSem+" = ? AND "+Numjour+ " > ? AND "+Categorie+ " = ? " , new String[]{String.valueOf(Annee), String.valueOf(Selectedweek), String.valueOf(Yesterday),SelectedCategorie}, null, null,NumSem+" AND "+Numjour+" AND "+Heure+" AND "+Minute+" ASC");
```

Comment: Use `DESC` for descending and `ASC` for ascending.

Comment: I am using asc in my code and the result is well sorted , my problem is when I close and open the app. the result is the sorting result of the first information I seized then the sorting result of the second information

Comment: This means that you aren't sorting the set when your app starts. If it's not the case please post all the relevant code in the question itself, otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: `AND` in an `ORDER BY` does not do what you seem to think it does. Refer to any decent SQL guide or reference or tutorial for the correct syntax for sorting by multiple columns.

Comment: @BackSlash: the database is sorted correctly when I open my application an only one time, the problem is the second time I open it the database is still sorted as I want it to be sorted but the problem is that it is sorted also by the seize date and I did not ask for it.Example: date 1: 1-2-3 date 2: 1-2-3 ; when I sort this informations seized in two different session I obtain 1-2-3-1-2-3 and not 1-1-2-2-3-3

Comment: @backslash, you were right :) the syntax was wrong

Comment: @amitava I gave you a wrong information, this is how the last part of the code should be   Numannee+" ASC, "+Numjour+" ASC, "+Heure+" ASC, "+Minute+" ASC");"

Comment: Well, if this is the code you put then you are getting as per the query. For ex. If you start feeding data to sql now then after two hours if you sort you will see the first hour data sorted by minutes then the second hour data sorted by minutes. If you want to sort by time then you may use sql DATETIME, here is some basic information, https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp

Answer (score 0):

my problem was in the syntax, this is the correct code

```
c =bdd.query(Program_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {Numannee, Numjour, Heure, Minute, NomEvent, Adresse,Photo, Presentation, URL}, Numannee+" = ? AND "+NumSem+" = ? AND "+Numjour+ " > ? AND "+Categorie+ " = ? " , new String[]{String.valueOf(Annee), String.valueOf(Selectedweek), String.valueOf(Yesterday),SelectedCategorie}, null, null,Numannee+" ASC, "+Numjour+" ASC, "+Heure+" ASC, "+Minute+" ASC");"
```